# Creation of a prepared statement inside a loop

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

**For clarification:** I know that it's the right thing to create the `PreparedStatement` outside the loop. I've asked this question just out of curiosity.

---

Let's assume that I'm creating a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) inside a loop with always the same SQL query.

```
final String sql = "INSERT INTO ...";
while (condition) {
   ...
   PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
   // Fill values of the prepared statement
   // Execute statement
   ...
}
```

Is this useless since the `PreparedStatement` object is always created anew? Or does the underlying database recognise that it's always the same SQL query with which the `PreparedStatement` is created and reuses it?

Comment: Why are you creating the `PreparedStatement` inside the loop? Put the creation outside the loop and re-use it in the loop.

Comment: The point of a prepared statement is to prepare it once, and use it multiple times. Actual implementation may be up to the driver, but you'd have to check the spec to see if there are any actual rules regarding this.

Comment: @Jesper I know that it's better to create it ouside the loop. I've just asked this question out of curiosity. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some drivers do cache prepared statements, yes. For example, skim this Oracle documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/stmtcach.htm

I don't believe there's anything that requires this to be true for all drivers, although certainly it seems like a likely feature of many JDBC drivers. It sounds like MySQL might not do this:
[How to use MySQL prepared statement caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222019/how-to-use-mysql-prepared-statement-caching)

That said, if you really want to use prepared statements efficiently, it seems like hanging on to an instance of a prepared statement that you use on each loop iteration makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Great answer, and the only one actually providing details to the problem. "Implicit Statement Caching".

Answer (score 8):

**1.** If you are using the **same** `PreparedStatement` throughout the loop, then **its better you keep the** `PreparedStatement` **outside the loop**.

**2.** If you have **sql statment which keeps changing inside the loop**, then only  its worth using it in the loop.

**3.** Moreover if its keep changing, then just use `Statement` **instead of** `PreparedStatement`, else the very purpose of PreparedStatement **is lost as you keep changing it.**

Comment: user321068 knows how to use it correctly, he asks what happens if he does not.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways so far i know.

1st Way

Its insert record one by one

```
final String sql = "INSERT INTO tablename(columnname) Values(?)";

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

while (condition) {
statement.setString(1,value);
statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

(or)

2nd way

It inserts all record as bulk insert

```
final String sql = "INSERT INTO tablename(columnname) Values(?)";

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

while (condition) {
statement.setString(1,value);
statement.addBatch();
}

statement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: user321068 knows how to use it correctly, he asks what happens if he does not.

Comment: Can you explain a little more detail on which aspect you asking?

Answer (score 1):

It is useless to create it everytime. See the link http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365244/Why-Prepared-Statements-are-important-and-how-to-use-them-properly

Comment: user321068 knows how to use it correctly, he asks what happens if he does not.

Answer (score 1):

Also try disable autocommit with [Connection.setAutoCommit(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) and that you use [PreparedStatement.executeBatch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: user321068 knows how to use it correctly, he asks what happens if he does not.