# java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have Java code that creates a MySQL database connection, and then processes a text file line-by-line. For each line (string), it parses it and creates a `PreparedStatement` that gets executed. The `PreparedStatement` inserts a new entry in a table in the database that I connected to.

My file contains thousands of lines, and I get this error: `java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. How do I do this kind of operation more memory-efficiently? I've read about making a batch of MySQL statements and then executing the batch. Would that be helpful for my situation?

Comment: Do you really create new PreparedStatement for each line instead of create PreparedStatement once and set it's parameters lint by line?

Comment: Yes, I do. How would I execute multiple INSERT statements with one PreparedStatement?

Comment: Add your code to question

Comment: You can create a single PreparedStatement (with `?` parameters) and then reuse it for thousands of rows. Just set the different values each time and run it.

Comment: Check this - looks like it contains answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971635/creation-of-a-prepared-statement-inside-a-loop

Comment: Can you post some code/examples?